# Error bound for Composite Simpson's Rule for $f\notin C^4$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

The Composite Simpson's Rule gives:

If $f\in C^4[a,b]$ and $h=(b-a)/n$ ($n$ is even), then the error term will be
$$
\frac{b-a}{180}h^4f^{(4)}(\mu)$$
for some $\mu\in (a,b)$.

My question is what the error term will be like if we apply Composite Simpson's Rule to a function $f\notin C^4$. Take the following function where $f\in C^2$ but $f\notin C^3$ for example:

$$
f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       2+\frac{4}{5}x+\frac{1}{5}x^3 & : x \in [0,1]\\
       3+\frac{7}{5}(x-1)+\frac{3}{5}(x-1)^2 & : x \in [1,2]
     \end{array}
   \right.
$$

If we apply the rule with $n=8$ to the interval $[0,2]$, what will be the error?